# Do action only if record is new

Tags: c#, ajax

In ASP.NET/C# I am using AJAX Timer. In Timer Tick I am using following code to periodically retrieve new data from backend.

**My code is** (Something of this kind)

```
OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    string abcxyz = dr[0].ToString();
    chat.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(abcxyz + "<br/>"));
}
MyConnection.Close();
```

In the above code I am retrieving thousands of values from server using `while loop`. Fine, now I want to make an action such as **only in the new attempt (As per timer tick) if values changes from previous attempt them perform the condition.*

I need the logic of the `IF` condition there

Some thing like

```
    OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string abcxyz = dr[0].ToString();
            ** // If the string abcxyz value changes from previous Tick function to Current Tick function then only do the next
                {
                chat.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(abcxyz + "<br/>"));
                }
                else
                {
                  // do nothing
                }
        }
        MyConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a private variable `private string previous_accxyz` and assign it after this code.

```
string abcxyz = dr[0].ToString();
if (!abcxyz.Equals(previous_accxyz))
{
    previous_accxyz = abcxyz;

    // do code
    chat.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(abcxyz + "<br/>"));
}
```

Comment: but where should I use `private string previous_accxyz` how come a private class access other class?

Comment: put the declaration of `private string previous_accxyz` outside the method, but inside your class.